# Why does the algorithm expression result get trucated?

Tags: bash, shell

If I run  `$((0x100 - 0 & 0xff))`, I got `0`.

However  `$((0x100 - 0))` gives me `256`.

Why the result from the first expression got truncated?

Comment: Because `256 & 0xff` (i.e. `256 & 255`) is zero. This is more a questions about mathematics than about shell programming.

Answer (score 3):

Because `&` is a bitwise operator, and there are no matching bits in `0x100` and `0xff`.

What that means is it looks at the bits that make up your numbers and you get a `1` back in the position where both inputs have a `1`.

So if you do `$((0x06 & 0x03))`

In binary you end up with
6 = `0110`
3 = `0011`

So when you logical and those together, you'll get

`0010` (binary) or `0x02`

For the numbers you have, there are no bits in common:

`0x100` in binary is
`0000 0001 0000 0000`

`0xff` in binary is
`0000 0000 1111 1111`

If you bitwise and them together, there are no matching bits, so you'll end up with
`0000 0000 0000 0000`

Interestingly, it does the subtraction before it does the bitwise and operation (I expected it to do the other way):

`$((0x100 - 1 & 0xff))` gives 255 or `0xff` because `0x100 - 1` = `0xff`

Comment: Note that if you override the operator precedence with `$((0x100 - (0 & 0xff) ))`, it does give 0 as the result (because `0 & 0xff` is 0).